# Show "Access Denied" message in magento

Tags: magento

In magento, we can add the user role and define the permission. But I want to display some part of collection. Although I have implement this by adding custom sql in admin grid. But if a user clicks on edit form, He can change the id from the url. So I want to throw a custom access denied message when user change the id from the url.

`Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Access Denied.'));`

I tried to add the above code on edit page with If statement. Although It works fine but it will show the "error" page to user. I only want to display "Access Denied" as it appears when a user does not have permission of specific extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Got The solution 
I have implemented the custom Access denied message by following code.

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    if(custom condition){ return false; }
    return true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you are throwing an exception; you could try something like this instead:

```
$message = $this->__('Access Denied.');
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
```

and for showing success messages in admin panel you can use `addSuccess`.